# C# Fluent Nhibernate Multitable Join on Or condition

Tags: c#, nhibernate, join, fluent

I want to execute this Query with CreateCriteria, I dont know if it's possible to add a OR clause to the ON part of the JOIN like this: (TZ.CodigoPuesto1_id = CP.Id or TZ.CodigoPuesto2_id = CP.Id), here is the complete query:

```
SELECT TZ.* 
FROM ConfigLinea as CL 
    JOIN Puesto as P ON P.ConfigLinea_id = CL.Id 
    join CodigoPuesto as CP ON CP.Puesto_id = P.Id 
    Join Trazabilidad as TZ ON 
        (TZ.CodigoPuesto1_id = CP.Id or TZ.CodigoPuesto2_id = CP.Id) 
WHERE TZ.Codigo1 = '{0}' OR TZ.Codigo2 = '{1}' AND CL.Id = {2}
```

So far I tried this, but is not generating the Query I need:

```
IList<Trazabilidad> result = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Trazabilidad), "TZ")
     .CreateAlias("CodigoPuesto1", "CP1")
     .CreateAlias("CodigoPuesto2", "CP2")
     .Add(Expression.Disjunction() //esto es un OR
         .Add(Restrictions.Eq("TZ.Codigo1", codigo))
         .Add(Restrictions.Eq("TZ.Codigo2", codigo))
     )
     .Add(Expression.Disjunction() //esto es un OR
         .Add(Restrictions.Eq("P1.ConfigLinea", cl))
         .Add(Restrictions.Eq("P2.ConfigLinea", cl))
     )
     .List<Trazabilidad>();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without your domain model it's hard to actually test this, but I think you'll want something like this. Basically the idea is the use the version of CreateAlias that lets you pass an ICriterion in as a parameter.

```
IList<Trazabilidad> result = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Trazabilidad), "TZ")
 .CreateAlias("CodigoPuesto1", "CP1")
 .CreateAlias("CodigoPuesto2", "CP2", JoinType.None, 
     Restrictions.Disjunction()
        .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("TZ.Codigo1", "CP.Id"))
       .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("TZ.Codigo2", "CP.Id"))
 )
 .Add(Expression.Disjunction() //esto es un OR
     .Add(Restrictions.Eq("P1.ConfigLinea", cl))
     .Add(Restrictions.Eq("P2.ConfigLinea", cl))
 )
 .List<Trazabilidad>()
```

Comment: Thanks, This gave me some ideas though it's not exactly what I need since it creates a different query.

I need to filter the join like this:
    TZ ON (TZ.CodigoPuesto1_id = CP.Id or TZ.CodigoPuesto2_id = CP.Id)

Comment: I edited it to generate that query. Basically instead of just saying codigo for the right hand side of the Restrictions, you can also put any valid criterion projection.

Comment: Expression.Disjunction() -> Really helped me a lot, Thanks, +1